# Meteor HTTP post request not working with google add place api

Tags: http, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I am using a HTTP post request to add places with google api in meteor js. The code I used is

```js
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key="+googleKey;
Meteor.http.post(url,
    {params: {
          "location": {
            "lat": -33.8669710,
            "lng": 151.1958750
          },
          "accuracy": 50,
          "name": "Google Shoes!",
          "phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
          "address": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia",
          "types": ["shoe_store"],
          "website": "http://www.google.com.au/",
          "language": "en-AU"
        }
    },function(err, result){
        console.log(arguments);
    })
```

Am getting an error

```js
     { [Error: failed [400] {    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" } ]
```

I had tried with changing the params and googleKey,but there is no change in the error. Can somebody help me to use http post request with google api? Thanks in advance

Comment: use `request` module from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/request . I dont think that Meteor.http has `https` post support.

Comment: @MariusDarila is there any way to use request module in meteor js?

Comment: which meteor version you use? https://atmospherejs.com/froatsnook/request for meteor 1.2

Comment: @MariusDarila Meteor 1.2.1

Comment: `request.postSync(uri, options); ` from https://atmospherejs.com/froatsnook/request would do the job for you

Comment: @MariusDarila ok, I am working on it

Comment: @MariusDarila but am getting the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100981/discussion-between-pooja-jayaraj-and-marius-darila).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `data` in place of `params` ?

```
Meteor.http.post(url,
    {data: {
          "location": {
            "lat": -33.8669710,
            "lng": 151.1958750
          },
          "accuracy": 50,
          "name": "Google Shoes!",
          "phone_number": "(02) 9374 4000",
          "address": "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia",
          "types": ["shoe_store"],
          "website": "http://www.google.com.au/",
          "language": "en-AU"
        }
    },function(err, result){
        console.log(arguments);
    })
```

Works fine on my remote server, but in localhost I have an `INVALID_REQUEST` response, due to the key I think.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [FAQs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/faq#why_do_i_keep_receiving_status_request_denied) of the Places API documentation

> The "status": "REQUEST_DENIED" is returned by the Google Places API Web Service when:
>
> - You have not activated the Google Places API Web Service in the Google Developers Console.
> - The key parameter is missing from your request.
> - The key parameter does not match the your API key in the Google Developers Console.
> - Your API key has not been correctly set up in the Google Developers Console:
>
>   > - If you are using a browser key, check that your allowed referer(s) are correct.
>   > - If you are using a server key, check that your allowed IP(s) are correct.
>   > - Android and iOS keys are not supported, please use a Browser or Server key.
> - The request was not sent as an HTTPS request, HTTPS is required for all Google Places API Web Service requests.
> - The incorrect HTTP method was used to send the request:
>
>   > - All requests must be sent as a GET request except for Place Add.
>   > - All Place Add requests must be sent as a POST request.

The request body you specified looks complete, you can check out the Google Developer Console if you missed some configuration on it.

Hope this helps!